# How to import from sql server to hive using sqoop in java jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, hive, sqoop

I have a table in sql server which i should import it to hive with sqoop using jdbc in java, How can i connect to hive with sqoop using JDBC and import?

Answer (score 0):

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqoopdatabase --username sqoopuser --P --table employee -m 1 --hive-database hivelearning --hive-import --hive-drop-import-delims`